# Custom title when using shortcode

Tags: title

I found this code to have a custom title on WordPress

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_document_title', 'myFilterTitle', 10, 1);

function myFilterTitle($myTitle) 
{    
    return "$myTitle here";
}
```

and some of my pages uses this shortcode to create content

```
function digitSix()
{
      //some codes here;

      $var = "this is custom title";
      apply_filters('pre_get_document_title', $var);

      return $someContent;
}

add_shortcode("i_digit6", "digitSix");
```

I was able to modify the title but it only gives "**here**" since it is a hard coded text inside the function **myFilterTitle($myTitle)**

It seems that the argument **$myTitle** I passed wasn't captured by the function.

Comment: your shortcode doesn't return content. try with `return apply_filters('pre_get_document_title', $var);`

Comment: You'll want add_filter, not apply_filter. But keep in mind that shortcodes are evaluated in the content, and the title has already been sent at that stage.

Answer (score 0):

This code solved my problem.

```
function digitSix()
{
      //some codes here;

      $var = "this is custom title";

      add_filter( 'pre_get_document_title', function( $var ) use ( $var ) {
            return $var;
        }, 20 );

      return $someContent;
}

add_shortcode("i_digit6", "digitSix");
```